# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: fullname. When using NativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

Getting:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: fullname.
```

Only when using `NativeQuery` in `Hibernate` with `JasperReports`.

When I use JPA criteria query then there's no issue

**JPA Criteria**

```
try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery Client criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Client.class);
    Root root = criteriaQuery.from(Client.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
    return session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

But when I use NativeQuery I face
`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: fullname.`

**Native Query :**

```
try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
    List<Client> query = session.createNativeQuery("select c.*, p.*
        from client c join product p on c.pid = p.id where c.id = :id")
        .addEntity("c", Client.class).addJoin("p", "c.product")
        .setParameter("id", id).list();
    return query;
}
```

Here Jasper JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Quotation" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="600" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3954e5eb-656a-454e-b9e5-35f7e5262d48">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="fullname" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="mobile" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="quotationNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="valid" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="product.description" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="product.cost" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="product.name" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

Client.java:

```
public class Client  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer id;
 private Product product;
 private String fullname;
 private String business;
 private String address;
 private String city;
 private String mobile;
 private String addedBy;
 private String date;
 private String status;
 private String quotationNo;
 private String valid;
 private String productName;
 private Set orderses = new HashSet(0);

public String getFullname() {
    return this.fullname;
}

public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}
```

I've already removed  from fields in Jasper JRXML

I also tried passing and removing false parameter in `new JRBeanColllectionDataSource(collection, false);` as follow,

```
new JRBeanColllectionDataSource(collection);
```

Passing `"false" parameter` only works for `JPA criteria` for `Native query` it doesn't matter whether parameter is passed or not it gives

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: fullname.
```

I'm trying `NativeQuery` to improve speed of `JasperReport` which is suggested for my previous question

So solution I want either for this one or for my previous question
[Jasper Reports 6.14 filling and generating report is so slow [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645336/jasper-reports-6-14-filling-and-generating-report-is-so-slow?noredirect=1#comment112609310_63645336)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is `select c.*, p.* from ...` so Hibernate returns a list of 2-elements arrays: the 1st element is the `Client` and the 2nd is the `Product`.

Even though it compiles, the result of the query is not a `List<Client>`.

You need to convert that list of arrays into a list of `Client` before sending it to Jasperreports

Comment: thank you so much I have noticed it earlier but that doe not matter what way I'm fetching data to fill reports it delays for first time approx 27 seconds and then it takes 5,4,2 and sometimes 0 second for second time. If you know cause please share.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing exactly but I suspect the issue is not in the Hibernate query. Try measuring the actual time it takes to run the query first. The 27 seconds spent on the first report might be initializing something, for instance the Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: I'm sure it is initialize jasper report but don't know which part. When I click on button to fetch 1000 records it doesn't much delay as jasper reports. And SessionFactory I'm using singletone class to start so there's no issue with SessionFatory.

Comment: I've enabled `hibernate.generate_statistics` query executing in nanoseconds so pretty sure it is jasper report's issue. :-(